# Asymptotic Expansion to find leading behavior term

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the asymptotic expansion to get the leading order term of $$I(x)=\int_0^{2\pi} (1+t^2) e^{x\cos t} dt$$ as $x\to\infty$.

The way I am approaching this is by first looking at the phase function $\phi(t)=\cos t$ which has two maxima in our interval of integration (one maxima at $t=0$ and one at $t=2\pi$). Since it has two maxima, I thought it might be a good idea to split the integral up into two integrals around each maxima. So, I write
\begin{align}
I(x)&=\int_0^{\pi} (1+t^2) e^{x\cos t} dt+\int_\pi^{2\pi} (1+t^2) e^{x\cos t} dt\\
&\sim\int_0^{\delta} (1+t^2) e^{x\cos t} dt+\int_{2\pi-\delta}^{2\pi} (1+t^2) e^{x\cos t} dt
\end{align}
since the major contribution is coming from the regions around the two maxima.

Just looking at the first integral, which I call $I_A=\int_0^{\delta} (1+t^2) e^{x\cos t} dt$, I can Taylor expand the phase function around $t=0$, so $\phi(t)\approx 1-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^4}{24}-\ldots=1-\frac{t^2}{2}+\{HOT\}$ where $\{HOT\}$ is higher order terms. For this to be justifiable, I need this Taylor Series to be ordered, so I need $xt^4\ll \mathcal{O}(1)\implies x\delta^4\ll \mathcal{O}(1)\implies$ we can pick $\delta\ll x^{-1/4}\to 0$ as
$x\to\infty$.

Now, I can write  $$I_A=e^x\int_0^\delta (1+t^2) e^{-\frac{xt^2}{2}} e^{x\{HOT\}} dt.$$

This looks similar to the form of Watson's lemma where I might be able to express this in terms of a Gamma function to get the asymptotic expansion, but I am not sure how to continue with Watson's lemma or if this is even correct since I have $e^x$ in front which is blowing up as $x\to\infty$, so it doesn't seem like a proper asymptotic expansion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method?wprov=sfla1) help?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I thought of using Laplace's method but am not sure how exactly to apply it here?

Comment: Did you look under "Other formulations" section? Your problem looks to be virtually in the exact form to directly apply. Agree?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Oh I see now, thanks for that! Would it still be a problem that I have $e^x$ multiplying outside my integral and that would blow up? Also, is what I am doing by splitting up the integral into two parts around each maxima valid?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson And also, how to I treat the $e^{x\{HOT\}}$ terms that I have when I am applying Laplace method as you mentioned?

Comment: I was saying apply the method in the article to the original integral $I(x)$. That should give you the leading term you're looking for.

Comment: i think this one or a close relative can be found as an example in Bender&Orzag where the calculations are done using steepest descent

Comment: @AaronHendrickson The problem with applying this directly is that I have two maxima (one at $t=0$ and another at $t=2\pi$). This method only works when there is one global maximum. Not sure how to use it in this case?

Comment: @asgeige I am actually using Bender and Orzag. Any idea where to look?

Comment: Try breaking it up into two integrals so that each integral contains only one maxima. Then apply Laplace formula to each integral.

Answer (score 3):

We have
\begin{align*}
I(x) = \int_0^{2\pi } {(1 + t^2 )\mathrm{e}^{x\cos t} \mathrm{d}t} & = \int_0^\pi  {(1 + t^2 )\mathrm{e}^{x\cos t} \mathrm{d}t}  + \int_\pi ^{2\pi } {(1 + t^2 )\mathrm{e}^{x\cos t} \mathrm{d}t} \\ & = \int_0^\pi  {\left[ {2 + t^2  + (2\pi  - t)^2 } \right]\mathrm{e}^{x\cos t} \mathrm{d}t} .
\end{align*}
Thus, by [Laplace's method](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.iii),
$$
I(x) = \sqrt {2\pi }(1 + 2\pi ^2 ) \mathrm{e}^x x^{ - 1/2} (1 + \mathcal{O}(x^{ - 1/2} ))
$$
as $x\to +\infty$.